# Bluetooth not working, hciconfig up time out

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, bluetooth

When I installed Linux Mint 20.3 on my Asus TUF FX506HCB, Touchpad, Secondary GPU and wireless card (MediaTek MT7921) didn't work so I installed Linux Kernel 5.13.0-30 from update manager.
Now almost everything is working well except Bluetooth.

When I try to turn it on from Bluetooth app, the switch turns on but it can't find any device neither other devices can find it. Renaming option is disabled also.
[image: Bluetooth app]

I tried `rfkill` to block and unblock Bluetooth; no difference.

```
$ rfkill
ID TYPE      DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
 0 bluetooth hci0   unblocked unblocked
 1 wlan      phy0   unblocked unblocked
```

When I run `hciconfig -a` this is the output:

```
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
BD Address: 00:00:00:00:00:00  ACL MTU: 0:0  SCO MTU: 0:0
DOWN 
RX bytes:0 acl:0 sco:0 events:0 errors:0
TX bytes:3 acl:0 sco:0 commands:1 errors:0
Features: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
Packet type: DM1 DH1 HV1 
Link policy: 
Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT
```

I think something is wrong with it because almost everything is `00`. When I tried to turn it on:

```
$ sudo hciconfig hci0 up
Can't init device hci0: Connection timed out (110)
```

`bluetoothctl list` and `hcitool dev` return no device.

Output of `lspci -k`:

```
...
0000:02:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. Device 7961
Subsystem: AzureWave Device 4680
Kernel driver in use: mt7921e
Kernel modules: mt7921e
...
```

Bluetooth service is also running:

```
$ sudo systemctl status bluetooth
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2022-03-07 00:36:02 +0330; 28min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 824 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 18760)
     Memory: 1.5M
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─824 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd
```

Just one time Bluetooth worked well and I managed to send a file from phone to laptop. After restart, it stopped working again.
Reinstalling kernel and Bluetooth related packages didn't help.

Bluetooth is working well on Windows 11 so there is no hardware problem.

Is there any solution or I should wait for next kernels to fix it?